# Response opencv (numpy) images with flask

Tags: python, image, opencv, flask, video-streaming

Since I heard about problems, caused by writing to SD-Cards many times, I want to serve my Images on a flask app (running on raspberry pi) directly using a file like object. In my application I process Images every few seconds and need to display them on a web interface using flask.

I'm actually trying something like this:

```
@app.route('/image')
def image():
    img = cv2.imread('raw.png')
    img_str = cv.imencode('.png', img)[1].tostring()
    f = io.BytesIO()
    f.write(img_str)
    f.seek(0)
    #return Response(bytes, mimetype='image/jpeg')
    return send_file(f, mimetype='image/png')
```

My goal is to call this function from the web interface using ajax a few times per second, to update the image. Maybe also longterm polls can be used instead of fixed frequency. For now I want to serve the image without writing it to the sdcard. The code example returns in an "Image can not be displayed since it contains errors.."

I'm new to flask, and also to opencv so any advice would help. Also let me know if there is an easy or better way to serve frequently updating images using builtin stream objects, socketio or whatever.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way :

```
@app.route('/image')
def image():
    img = cv2.imread('raw.png')
    data = cv.imencode('.png', img)[1].tobytes()
    return Response(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + data + b'\r\n\r\n', mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'
```